# Problem with WinSCP connect to Oracle VM Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have followed the following steps shown in the web links below to connect my WinSCP installed in windows 10 to connect with Ubuntu in Oracle VM Virtualbox that uses the resources in my laptop. Windows 10 and Ubuntu VM virtualbox are installed in the same laptop sharing resources. But, I am still getting an error "Network error: Connection to "127.0.0.1" refused.

Can somebody help me to connect my WinSCP to Ubuntu virtual box?

Thanks in advance,

https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=937&ei=B_fyXIrNEc64sQXFnKzICw&q=WinSCP+connect+to+Oracle+VM+Virtualbox&oq=WinSCP+connect+to+Oracle+VM+Virtualbox&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5648.9199..12219...1.0..0.118.815.5j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i13i30j0i13i5i30j33i10.PMZacYmDf-o#kpvalbx=1

https://medium.com/platform-engineer/port-forwarding-for-ssh-http-on-virtualbox-459277a888be

Comment: A couple issues here: First "127.0.0.0.1"  is an invalid IP. Should be 127.0.0.1. But if I am following your question correctly, your real problem is this:  From your Windows host you must make the request to the Ubuntu *guest* IP address.

Comment: @Stephen. It was a typo. I have corrected in the above question. How can i make the request from Windows to Ubuntu guest IP address?

Comment: In the table you show in the tutorial,there is a column showing guest IP? Use that instead of the 127.0.0.1. I think I remember that. Or, in a terminal window on your Ubuntu server issue `ip address show`. You will see a list that includes `BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP`. That device will gave an IPv4 address listed at `inet n.n.n.n/24 brd...`. In your winscp client dialog, use that IP address.